# passing bounds to google places API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm just starting to play with the Google Places API (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html) but I can't seem to get the syntax right for passing in bounds rather than a latLng object and radius.

In the API docs it says:

> This method takes a request with the following fields:
>   Either of:
>   bounds, which must be a google.maps.LatLngBounds object defining the rectangle in which to search; or
>   a location and radius; the former takes a google.maps.LatLng object, and the radius takes a simple integer, representing the circle's radius in meters.

My code looks like this:

```
var bnds      = map.getBounds();
console.log(bnds); // this returns a valid bounds object!
var req       = {
                 bounds: bnds
              };
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.search(req, callback);
```

When I run the page, I get an error `Uncaught Error: Property bounds not specified` from the Google service. If I change the req object to

```
var req    = {
               location: latlngobject,
               radius: '500'
             }
```

it works properly. Any idea on the proper syntax for passing in the bounds object rather than the lat/lng/radius?

Comment: Also should add that I get the same error when submitting
`var req. . .location: bnds`

Comment: I get "Property location is not specified." when passing in bounds only. Did you ever resolve this? Seems to be a bug in the API.

Answer (score 2):

2020 Update:
[Maps v3 has `nearbySearch` and `textSearch`, which both accept bounds as a location.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests)

Answer (score 1):

The docs **do** shows that bounds is an option:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests

> Either of:
>   bounds, which must be a google.maps.LatLngBounds object defining the rectangular search > area; or
>   a location and radius; the form .....

I had this issue, so I took out the other parameters as the full error shows:

> Uncaught Error: Property bounds is invalid (perhaps because of other properties).

So take out the rankBy or keywords or types parameters, until it works - then add them back

These parameters work for me:

    `var arg = {
        bounds:map.getBounds(),
        types:['bar','airport']
    };`

Make the types as full as you want it.

Bounds works better for me in the radar search than in the nearbySearch

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the Google Places API does not have a bounds option/parameter. I don't see it mentioned anywhere here at least: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

radius only it seems.

Comment: bounds is an option see this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests

Comment: @Mike, your link points to Google Places API (a web service, HTTP) and this discussion goes about Google Maps Api Places Library (front-end, Javascript). It is a shame there is no bounds parameter in de back-end API.

Answer (score 0):

The following example shows you how to obtain the bounds from a `Geocoder()` result and limit your `PlacesService()` results to it and assign the appropriate default Places Markers.

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(),
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }),
    rect = new google.maps.Rectangle({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.3,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.33,
        map: map
    }),
    markers_amount = 10,
    markers = [];

// GEOCODE
geocoder.geocode({
    'address': 'Vienna'
}, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var geometry = results[0].geometry,
            places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

        map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
        // SETS THE BOUNDS HERE
        rect.setBounds( bounds );

        places.search({
            bounds: bounds,
            // https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types
            types: [
                // Until there's enough meta data for Google, 
                // they label everything as an 'establishment'.
                'establishment'
            ]
        }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                console.log( results );
                for (var i = 0; i < markers_amount; i++) {
                    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: results[i].geometry.location,
                        map: map,
                        icon: image = {
                            url: results[i].icon,
                            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                        }
                    }));
                }
            }
        });
        //console.log(markers);
    } else {
        return $('#map').html('could not locate you');
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe this code snippet will help you

var bounds = map.getBounds();
var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest(); 
  var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast(); 
  var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
  var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();

Comment: This doesn't really solve any issue with the Places API as described above.